# Transfer data in Excel attachment, in Outlook or Gmail, to Google sheet

Tags: excel, vba, google-apps-script, google-sheets, outlook

I daily receive an email in Outlook with an Excel sheet attached.

I am working with dashboard/templates in Google data studio, and Google sheets. To make this work smoothly, I need to transfer the data from the Excel sheet to my Google sheet automatically. Is this possible?

My first thought was to send the attached Excel sheets to my gmail instead, because from here I could write a script that gets the data from the gmail. This was more complicated than I thought.

Maybe a VBA code to transfer the attached Excel file to google-drive, and then from there I could update my Google sheet? Is this possible?

Note: I am not experienced enough to write VBA/APP script from scratch.

Comment: How do you recognise this email?  Does it have a particular subject?  Is it from a particular sender?  I assume a google drive looks like any other drive to a Windows program.  If a google drive does look like any other drive, then you can save attachments to it.  I suspect the easiest approach is to specify a rule to identify the email and then attach a script to save the attachment.

Comment: Actually this is not as hard as it seems, though I accept as a novice coder it presents a Mt Everest challenge - which we can assist with. But generally speaking, this topic has been covered before: [Is there any google API which could save gmail message attachments to google drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48526166/1330560) and [Convert all xls files available in a folder into “Google Doc Spreadsheets”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25368566/1330560)

Comment: Are you capable of writing the macro that would "automatically" forward an Outlook mail item, with Excel attachment, to your GMail account? If not, then this is something that you ought to look into. As mentioned by @TonyDallimore, there may be something distinctive about the Outlook mail (source, title, sender, recipient, etc) that will enable you to narrow the field to only specific emails.

Answer (score 2):

**Q:** The OP asks: is it possible to transfer an Excel spreadsheet, received as an Outlook attachment, to google-drive, and then update it to a Google Sheet format?

**A:** Yes.

---

**Q:** What are the discrete steps required to satisfy the OP's objective?
**A:**
1 - Write a macro in Outlook to automatically forward the email and Excel attachment to the OP's GMail account; specifically to the account used to log into Google Sheets. For the purposes of this answer this aspect, though fairly straightforward, this is treated as off topic.

2 - Create a folder (or folder/subfolder) in Google Drive where the Excel spreadsheet can be saved. This could be done manually or by script. "Manually" is easier, "by script" is more fun and offers more flexibility.

3 - Run a Google script to access the OP's Gmail account, identify Excel attachments (say, files ending with 'xls', 'xlsx', 'xlsm' - other variations can be added), and save the Excel file to the Google Drive folder. Attach a "label" to each relevant email so that only new unprocessed messages are processed.

4 - Run a Google script to access the Google Drive folder/subfolder and convert the Excel spreadsheet to a Google Sheet.

---

As noted in comments, this topic has been raised, in one form or another, many times before: [Is there any google API which could save gmail message attachments to google drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48526166/1330560) and [Convert all xls files available in a folder into “Google Doc Spreadsheets”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25368566/1330560) are two good examples. Google search will reveal many other topics - on StackOverflow and other sources.

However Google services (Docs, scripts, APIs, etc) are being constantly enhanced. One of the by-products of this development is that some methods are discontinued and this can render a previously correct answer to become out-of-date.

Unfortunately this is the case with the excellent `GmailToDrive()` function supplied in the Jan 2018 answer to [Is there any google API which could save gmail message attachments to google drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48526166/1330560). Google Advanced Drive Service and Drive API changed during 2018 and that excellent answer now falls at the last hurdle.

The following code is supplied in order to provide an update to February 2019.
The basis of this answer is the `GmailToDrive()` function provided by Mr.Rebot, but modified for Excel files.

---

**Trigger**

The code should be set as a time-driven, Installable Trigger. The frequency will vary from case to case. The OP can make their own assessment. There are other sources that are available to explain this.

---

**Drive API**

The OP must activate the Drive API (Advanced Services as well as the Google Cloud Platform API Dashboard). For the sake of clarity, a brief outline of the steps is at the end of this answer.

---

**Code**

```
// GLOBALS
// Array of file extension which you would like to extract to Drive
var fileTypesToExtract = ['xls', 'xlsx', 'xlsm'];

//Name of the folders in google drive in which files will be put
var homeFolder = "009-StackExchange"; // a folder branching from the root
var ExcelFolderName = "010-GmailToDrive"; // sub folder of "homeFolder"

//Name of the label which will be applied after processing the mail message
var emaillabelName = 'GmailToDrive';

function so54755021()
// an adaptation of function GmailToDrive()
{

  //build query to search emails
  var query = '';

  // loop through the filestoextract and add to query
  for (var i in fileTypesToExtract) {
    query += (query == '' ? ('filename:' + fileTypesToExtract[i]) : (' OR filename:' + fileTypesToExtract[i]));
  }
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: #01 the query is: " + query); //DEBUG

  query = 'in:inbox has:nouserlabels ' + query;
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: #02 the query is: " + query); //DEBUG

  var threads = GmailApp.search(query);
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: threads = " + threads + "; threads length = " + threads.length); //DEBUG

  var label = getGmailLabel_(emaillabelName);
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: label = " + label); //DEBUG (GmailToDrive)

  var parentFolder;

  if (threads.length > 0) {
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: threads length is more than zero");//DEBUG

    //Logger.log("DEBUG: folder name = " + folderName); //DEBUG  
    //parentFolder = getFolder_(folderName); // subroutine

    // build sub-folder if necessary
    createDriveFolder(homeFolder, ExcelFolderName);
    parentFolder = homeFolder;

  }


  for (var i in threads) {
    var mesgs = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j in mesgs) {
      //get attachments
      var attachments = mesgs[j].getAttachments();
      for (var k in attachments) {
        var attachment = attachments[k];
        //Logger.log("DEBUG: attachment: " + attachment);//DEBUG

        var isExcelType = checkIfExcel_(attachment);
        //Logger.log("DEBUG: isExceltype = " + isExcelType);//DEBUG

        if (!isExcelType) continue;

        // Copy the Blob
        var attachmentBlob = attachment.copyBlob();
        //Logger.log("DEBUG: attachmentblob = " + attachmentBlob);//DEBUG

        var ExcelFolderObject = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(ExcelFolderName).next();

        //Create the Excel file in Google Drive
        var file = ExcelFolderObject.createFile(attachmentBlob);

        // get the file name and ID
        var fileid = file.getId();
        var filename = file.getName();
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: file = " + file + ", and ID = " + fileid + ", and file name: " + filename);//DEBUG
        var fileType = file.getMimeType()
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: the MIME type is " + fileType);//DEBUG

        // copy the Blob again in preparation for conversion
        var xBlob = file.getBlob();

        // get the folder ID to copy the file
        var folderId = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(ExcelFolderName).next().getId();

        // set parameters for the new file
        var newFile = {
          title: filename + '_converted',
          key: fileid,
          parents: [{
            "id": folderId
          }]

        }

        // convert the file
        var convfile = Drive.Files.insert(newFile, xBlob, {
          convert: true
        });
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: the converted file is " + convfile);//DEBUG

      }
    }

    // Add the label to the Gmail item
    threads[i].addLabel(label);
  }
}


// If necessary, create the label in GMail
function getGmailLabel_(name) {
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(name);
  if (label == null) {
    label = GmailApp.createLabel(name);
  }
  return label;
}

function createDriveFolder(baseFolder, folderName) {

  var baseFolderObject = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(baseFolder).next();
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: basefolderobject = " + baseFolderObject);//DEBUG
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(baseFolder).next().getFolders();
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: folders: "+folders);//DEBUG

  // set variable to detect a match
  var foldermatch = 0;

  //Loop through folders
  while (folders.hasNext()) {

    var folder = folders.next();
    //Logger.log(DEBUG: folder.getName());//DEBUG

    // If the folder name matches
    if (folder.getName() == folderName) {

      // update the match variable
      foldermatch = 1;
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: there's a match/folder exists: " + folder.getName());//DEBUG
    }
  }

  // Do something is there is a match
  if (foldermatch != 0) {
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: There was a match so do NOTHING");//DEBUG


  } else {
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: There was no match so create the folder"); //DEBUG
    baseFolderObject.createFolder(folderName);
  }

  // The folder already existed, or it has been created. Either way, our work is done.
  return;
}


// this function will check for filextension type.
// and return boolean
function checkIfExcel_(attachment) {
  var fileName = attachment.getName();
  var temp = fileName.split('.');
  var fileExtension = temp[temp.length - 1].toLowerCase();
  if (fileTypesToExtract.indexOf(fileExtension) != -1) return true;
  else return false;
}
```

---

**Enable the Drive Api**

1 - From the Script Editor, select Resources > Advanced Google Services; select Drive API and slide the switch to On.
[image: Advanced Google Services]

---

2 - Click the link to the "Google Cloud Platform API Dashboard"

---

3 - The Google Cloud Platform - APIs and Services screen opens in a new window.
Click the link to Enable APIs and Services
[image: Google Cloud Platform - Enable APIs and Services]

---

4 - Search for "drive", and then click the option for Drive API.
[image: Search for "drive"]

---

5 - Click the "Enable" button for the Drive API
[image]

---

6 - The system will display the Drive API details; note the Drive API is enabled.     Then just close this window.
[image: the Drive API is enabled]

---

7 - Click OK on the "Advances Google Services" screen (which has remained open all this time).
You're ready to run the script.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Very kind of you! I will look at these suggestion.